# Create DAX to count number of occupied rooms per calendar date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to count the number of "Occupied rooms" per calendar date.

so if there was say 6 reserves with diffrent "DateIN" and "DateOUT" I would be able to calculate how many rooms occupied there was every day. I have done this by using a column formula - but I need it to be a measure in order to be filtered by slicers.

Here is a simple example of what I would need:

```
BOOKINGID                     DateIN               DateOUT

000001                       01-01-2017          06-01-2017

000002                       01-01-2017          03-01-2017

000003                       02-01-2017          03-01-2017

000004                       03-01-2017          05-01-2017

000005                       08-01-2017          10-01-2017
```

```
DATE                     OCCUPIEDROOMS

01-01-2017                          2

02-01-2017                          3

03-01-2017                          3

04-01-2017                          2

05-01-2017                          2

06-01-2017                          1

07-01-2017                          0

08-01-2017                          1

09-01-2017                          1

10-01-2017                          1
```

here is a the formula i used to do this as a column:

> OcupacionHL = CALCULATE(count(F_Reservas[Reservas]); FILTER(F_Reservas;
>   (F_Reservas[Fecha Inicio] <= D_Calendario[FECHA]) && (F_Reservas[Fecha
>   Fin] >= D_Calendario[FECHA])); F_Reservas[Hotel] = "Hotel 1")

And here is an image of my data model:
[image: data model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure version of that calculation is not much different from what you tried.

```
OcupacionHL =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( F_Reservas[BookingID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( F_Reservas ),
        MAX ( Calendario[Fecha] ) >= [DateIN]
            && MAX ( Calendario[Fecha] ) <= [DateOUT]
    )
)
```

Just use `MAX(Calendario[Fecha])` to get the current date in context and you can use it to compare against the date range in `F_Reservas` table.

[image]

Note the calculation for `3/1/2017` is `4` instead of `3` in your example. Also `7/1/2017` has no bookings so it returns `BLANK` that's the reason it doesn't appear.