# Create DAX to count number of occupied rooms per calendar month date in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am new to power BI and dax, and have a question regarding calculating values by month. I am really using an excel formula and I am trying to use the wonders of power BI to help me filter this by month.
I am calculating the number of days that customers stay:
there is acolumn that calculates Lenght of stay - LOS is: [Check Out]-[Check In] but when it falls in 2 different months I would like to filter it by each month, how can I add this on the formula?
I did look at this post ([Create DAX to count number of occupied rooms per calendar date in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622149/create-dax-to-count-number-of-occupied-rooms-per-calendar-date-in-power-bi?rq=1))  but it seems that my formula is much simpler and I tried to adapt using that information but still to complicated. Anyone can help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjnU6.png)

[image]

[image: LOS4]

[image: LOS5]

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with the expected output, will be helpful to answer this.

Comment: Hi Sid29 I added the image, and the the problem here is one the LOS is more than 1 night, falling into only the January month, rather than 1 night January and 3 nights in February.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this formula (as a calculated column):

```
LOS = DATEDIFF('Date'[CheckIn];'Date'[CheckOut];DAY)
```

[image]

Now I add 2 Columns
First with the nights of First Month CheckIn and Other With the Nights of second Month of CheckOut:

```
LOS(MonthOfCheckIn) = IF(MONTH('Date'[Check In])>=MONTH('Date'[Check Out]);DATEDIFF('Date'[Check In];'Date'[Check Out];DAY);DATEDIFF('Date'[Check In];ENDOFMONTH('Date'[Check In]);DAY)+1)

LOS(MonthOfCheckOut) = IF(MONTH('Date'[Check In])<MONTH('Date'[Check Out]);DATEDIFF(STARTOFMONTH('Date'[Check Out]);'Date'[Check Out];DAY);0)
```

it works for me (as in the above image). Tell me please if this resolve your problem

Comment: Hi ptfaferreira, this doesn't work for me, it keeps telling can't find the table date! Any other ideas

Comment: I added the image from my power bi with your data. Maybe don't understand well your question? Is that the result you expect or different?

Comment: Hi ptfaferreira, this is the error image attached. I also have already amended ; for , and then still another error, image also attached LOS4

Comment: Maybe you need to use comma instead of semicolon. Depends the configuration of your PowerBI. Try to replace it and tell me if it works please ;)

Comment: Hi ptfaferreira, I have used the comma instead, and then there is another error. Indeed your image is the result I expect and also, when the dates fails in 2 months, that it will separate LOS per month. But as you can see I am having difficulties adding that formula as it always states incorrect...not sure why.

Comment: By your second image you need to replace Date by the name you are using in your table... Can you try it?

Comment: If this last change does´t work send us all original data you have in your table,  please.

Comment: Thanks ptfaferreira...everytime I solve a issue error, another comes back...so if I should i use Measure = DATEDIFF('CheckIn','Checkout',DAY)....I assume I only need one value on the data and use once the value CheckIn and CheckOut, but then yet another error shows!  See LOS5....

Comment: This error is quite simple to resolve, is only a issue of sintax in your DAX. As I said in the last comment you need to replace "Date" by the name you are using in your table. Now you only are givnig the name of column and the right sintax is: DATEDIFF('TableName'[ColumnName],'TableName'[ColumnName],DAY)

Comment: Hi ptfaferreira, thanks, it all worked out now. Still the all point of the post was to  it falls in 2 different months, for example check-in 30th January and check-out 4th February to split, 2 nights January and 3 nights February... this is still give me what a simple formula would give me a total of 5 nights. Thanks for your patience and help

Comment: Don't give up from your solution :) Maybe can have the result you want now. Please can you check?